# Add calculated column to pandas dataframe on the fly while iterating over the lines of a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I have a large space separated input file `input.csv`, which I can't hold in memory:

```
## Header
# More header here
A   B
1   2
3   4
```

If I use the `iterator=True` argument for [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), then it returns a `TextFileReader` / `TextParser` object. This allows filtering the file on the fly and only selecting rows for which column `A` is greater than 2.

But how do I add a third column to the dataframe on the fly without having to loop over all of the data once more?

Specifically I want column `C` to be equal to column `A` multiplied by the value in a dictionary `d`, which has the value of column `B` as its key; i.e. `C = A*d[B]`.

Currently I have this code:

```
import pandas
d = {2: 2, 4: 3}
TextParser = pandas.read_csv('input.csv', sep=' ', iterator=True, comment='#')
df = pandas.concat([chunk[chunk['A'] > 2] for chunk in TextParser])
print(df)
```

Which prints this output:

```
   A  B
1  3  4
```

How do I get it to print this output (`C = A*d[B]`):

```
   A  B  C
1  3  4  9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator to work on the chunks one at a time:

**Code:**

```
def on_the_fly(the_csv):
    d = {2: 2, 4: 3}
    chunked_csv = pd.read_csv(
        the_csv, sep='\s+', iterator=True, comment='#')

    for chunk in chunked_csv:
        rows_idx = chunk['A'] > 2
        chunk.loc[rows_idx, 'C'] = chunk[rows_idx].apply(
            lambda x: x.A * d[x.B], axis=1)
        yield chunk[rows_idx]
```

**Test Code:**

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(u"""#
    A   B
    1   2
    3   4
    4   4
""")

import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([c for c in on_the_fly(data)])
print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
   A  B     C
1  3  4   9.0
2  4  4  12.0
```